# Unsynchronized write in special field in POSIX shared memory

Tags: c, concurrency, synchronization, posix

I have some processes which need to communicate via POSIX shared memory.

The struct, which is stored in this shared memory looks like that:

```
struct shared_message{
  enum MESSAGE_TYPE type;
  [fields]
  uint8_t error;
};
```

Obviously I need to synchronize the access to the shared memory. But if one client fails or receives a SIGINT/SIGTERM signal, I want to notify the other clients of this error by setting shared_message->error to 1. 
The thing is, I can't really do this in a synchronized way, because I would prevent the process from beeing shut down in a timely manner after receiving a terminal signal.

Is it safe to just set the error variable to 1 without synchronizing the access? I do not care about "lost updates", because the only thing I do with this flag is setting it from zero to one, but I worry that it may be possible that writing to this flag may somehow interfere with nearby fields, for example because a whole DWORD is written, not just this one byte.

Comment: IME setting just one byte would work fine. And it is not "whole DWORD" (are you on Windows? why POSIX then?) but cache line (check "cache line alignment" questions here on SO). It might be inefficient to read/write one byte in presence of high level of concurrency, but IME on most CPU architectures just setting it from 0 to 1 would be atomic.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, cache line is the right term on POSIX. I don't care if its inefficient, this is an edge case anyway. I think I'll use a sig_atomic_t, then it should be guaranteed to be atomic.